# missing required keys, when linking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an applicaton that has Movie studios, Films, and Clips. Each Studio, has an associated film, and each film has associated clips. This content is uploaded solely by the admin of the website. Now, users are able to view various clips from films, and each time a clip is viewed by a user, an "impression" is created. I'm using the impressionist gem to track views on each clip. This ties into my next point.

In the admin backend I'd like to allow the admin to select a clip and choose a date range and then when they click filter it will display all of the users who viewed the clip in that given range.

I have this working in a table format, however, I'm un-able to display a link to the actual film or clip, I was able to display a link to the Studio with np.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<% if @impressions %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Studio</th>
    <th>Film</th>
    <th>Clip</th>

  </tr>
<% @impressions.each do |impression| -%>
<% @clip = Clip.where(id: impression.impressionable_id).first %>
<% @user = User.where(id: impression.user_id).first %>

    <tr>
    <th>
    <%= link_to @clip.film.studio.name,  saas_admin_studio_path(@clip.film.studio) %> < --- works fine!
    </th>
    <th>
    <%= link_to @clip.film.name, saas_admin_studio_film_path(@clip.film) %> <--- doesn't work (see error #1)
    </th>
    <th>
    <%=  link_to @clip.name, saas_admin_studio_film_clips_path(@clip) %> <--- doesn't work (see error #2)
    </th>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

**Error #1**:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in SaasAdmin::Statistics#search
Showing /Users/me/Sites/multi/app/views/saas_admin/statistics/index.html.erb where line #58 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"saas_admin/films", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :studio_id=>#<Film id: 5, name: "blab", sort_name: "blab", description: "<p>bla</p>", short_description: "bla", meta_data: "bla", studio_id: 4, active: true, trackable: true, regions: nil, created_at: "2014-07-25 01:21:48", updated_at: "2014-07-25 01:21:48", poster_file_name: "ABeautifulMind-ManySolutions.png", poster_content_type: "image/png", poster_file_size: 331462, poster_updated_at: "2014-07-25 01:21:46", permalink: "blab", amazon_link: "">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

**Error #2**:

```
    ActionController::UrlGenerationError in SaasAdmin::Statistics#search
Showing /Users/me/Sites/multi/app/views/saas_admin/statistics/index.html.erb where line #60 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"saas_admin/clips", :film_id=>nil, :format=>nil, :studio_id=>#<Clip id: 1, name: "test", sort_name: "test", permalink: "test", description: "<p>test</p>", duration: nil, film_id: 5, active: true, trackable: true, view_count: nil, status: nil, thumbnail_remote_file: "", created_at: "2014-07-25 01:22:12", updated_at: "2014-07-25 01:22:12", thumbnail_file_name: "ABeautifulMind-ManySolutions.png", thumbnail_content_type: "image/png", thumbnail_file_size: 331462, thumbnail_updated_at: "2014-07-25 01:22:11", impressions_count: 5, position: 1>} missing required keys: [:film_id]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Studio.rb:

```
class Studio < ActiveRecord::Base

  # attr_accessible :name, :code, :active, :trackable
  after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:studio)

  has_many :films, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :clips, :through => :films

end
```

Film.rb:

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:film)

  belongs_to :studio
  has_many :clips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :film_countries
  has_many :countries, :through => :film_countries, :source => :fcountry
 end
```

Clip.rb:

```
class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:clip)

  is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :unique => :request_hash

  the impressionist gem is tracking all of the views for us. And what do u want to render ?

  a list of results, between the two dates of  usofe rwhat of users who viewed the clip u selected

  belongs_to :film
  has_one :video, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :playlist_item
 end
```

**Edit 2:**

Routes:

```
sort_saas_admin_studio_film_clips POST     /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips/sort(.:format)     saas_admin/clips#sort
       saas_admin_studio_film_clips GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips(.:format)          saas_admin/clips#index
                                    POST     /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips(.:format)          saas_admin/clips#create
    new_saas_admin_studio_film_clip GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips/new(.:format)      saas_admin/clips#new
   edit_saas_admin_studio_film_clip GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips/:id/edit(.:format) saas_admin/clips#edit
        saas_admin_studio_film_clip GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips/:id(.:format)      saas_admin/clips#show
                                    PATCH    /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips/:id(.:format)      saas_admin/clips#update
                                    PUT      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips/:id(.:format)      saas_admin/clips#update
                                    DELETE   /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:film_id/clips/:id(.:format)      saas_admin/clips#destroy
            saas_admin_studio_films GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films(.:format)                         saas_admin/films#index
                                    POST     /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films(.:format)                         saas_admin/films#create
         new_saas_admin_studio_film GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/new(.:format)                     saas_admin/films#new
        edit_saas_admin_studio_film GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:id/edit(.:format)                saas_admin/films#edit
             saas_admin_studio_film GET      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:id(.:format)                     saas_admin/films#show
                                    PATCH    /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:id(.:format)                     saas_admin/films#update
                                    PUT      /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:id(.:format)                     saas_admin/films#update
                                    DELETE   /admin/content/studios/:studio_id/films/:id(.:format)                     saas_admin/films#destroy
                 saas_admin_studios GET      /admin/content/studios(.:format)                                          saas_admin/studios#index
                                    POST     /admin/content/studios(.:format)                                          saas_admin/studios#create
              new_saas_admin_studio GET      /admin/content/studios/new(.:format)                                      saas_admin/studios#new
             edit_saas_admin_studio GET      /admin/content/studios/:id/edit(.:format)                                 saas_admin/studios#edit
                  saas_admin_studio GET      /admin/content/studios/:id(.:format)                                      saas_admin/studios#show
                                    PATCH    /admin/content/studios/:id(.:format)                                      saas_admin/studios#update
                                    PUT      /admin/content/studios/:id(.:format)                                      saas_admin/studios#update
                                    DELETE   /admin/content/studios/:id(.:format)                                      saas_admin/studios#destroy
```

Comment: What associations do you have in between them and can you post output of rake routes?

Comment: I've updated the post with the appropriate models, displaying the associations. Also, the rake routes is quite long but the paths I've posted above are correct.

Comment: I think i know the problem but need to be sure that's why asked you to post routes. You can check controller specific routes by doing `rake routes CONTROLLER=controller_name` so it won't give you a long list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your error they say:

> missing required keys: [:id]
>
> missing required keys: [:film_id]

So the issue is your routes are nested and you are not passing full information to form proper routes. Try these links:

```
<%= link_to @clip.film.name, saas_admin_studio_film_path(@clip.film.studio, @clip.film) %>
<%= link_to @clip.name, saas_admin_studio_film_clips_path(@clip.film.studio ,@clip.film) %>
```

Comment: If these still doesn't work then need to see your routes

Comment: Updated with routes, I'll look over this answer now :)

Comment: Ah we're super close! clip.film.name worked.. the second one though, clip.name, returned the following: ouldn't find Studio with id=blab

Extracted source (around line #72):
  def load_parents
    @studio = Studio.find(params[:studio_id])

Comment: @SonnyBlack yeah updated second one. I was passing wrong variables, that's why i was asking for routes :)